# Inserting a CHAR into DATE in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am running into a problem. I have two DB2 tables, we can call them Table1 and Table2 for this question. Table1 has a column called Birthdate that is datatype CHAR and reads like '19781205'.

I need to insert some of the information from Table1 into Table2. Table2 has a DATE_OF_BIRTH column that is datatype DATE. I need to get Table1.Birthdate inserted into Table2.DATE_OF_BIRTH.

I have tried the following based on things I have seen online:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
(SELECT Name, TO_DATE(Birthdate,'yyyy-mm-dd') AS DATE_OF_BIRTH
FROM TABLE1)
```

And received this error: THE VALUE IS NOT COMPATIBLE WITH THE DATA TYPE OF ITS TARGET. TARGET NAME IS DATE_OF_BIRTH.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
(SELECT
Name, DATE(Birthdate, 'YYYYMMDD') AS DATE_OF_BIRTH
FROM TABLE1)
```

And received this error: THE NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS SPECIFIED FOR DATE IS INVALID.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
(SELECT
Name, Cast(Birthdate as date) AS DATE_OF_BIRTH
FROM TABLE2)
```

And received this error: THE DATE, TIME, OR TIMESTAMP VALUE *N IS INVALID.

It is probably just a case of I have been coding and working on this for too long that I cannot get my head wrapped around it.

Comment: Add dashes. For example '2017-04-29'.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the SELECT are completely useless

Answer (score 0):

This syntax should just work:

```
insert into table2(name, birthdate)
select name, to_date(birthdate, 'yyyymmdd') from table1
```

This is very close to your second attempt so I suspect that this is not exactly what you tried.

See **[this demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b4531edba9d4650ae65d89b18f5e6f8a)** for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Add dashes. For example:

```
create table a (d char(8));

insert into a (d) values ('20200107');
insert into a (d) values ('20170429');

create table b (d date);

insert into b (d)
select substr(d, 1, 4) || '-' ||
       substr(d, 5, 2) || '-' ||
       substr(d, 7, 2)
from a
```

Then:

```
select * from b;
```

Returns:

```
D         
----------
2020-01-07
2017-04-29
```